# How can I check the SQL syntax in a .sql file?

Tags: mysql, validation, syntax

How can I check the SQL syntax in a .sql file?

Comment: This needs a lot of clarification to be useful (and to stay open). Are you asking for tips on visually inspecting your SQL? Are you looking for a script that will help you check the syntax? Are you running the script and you need help understanding a particular error?

Comment: I think they want to verify that the file has valid mySql syntax.

Comment: visually inspecting SQL file or script will also do to check the syntax

Comment: @maxjackie said "visually inspecting SQL file or script will also do to check the syntax".  in my experience, humans are not 100% accurate checking syntax, but the DB is!

Comment: In an automation that accepts a set of migration/rollback scripts, knowing that they at least pass basic syntax sanity and failing the commit if they don't makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could paste it into a query browser like the MySQL Query Browser (part of the GUI Tools package) and visually inspect how the keywords and string literals are colored to more easily see if you've made any syntax errors.

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html

Answer (score 8):

`SELECT STATEMENT_DIGEST_TEXT` in MySQL 8.0 can be used for MySQL query syntax validation.

```
8.0.4>SELECT STATEMENT_DIGEST_TEXT('FLUSH TABLES')\G
STATEMENT_DIGEST_TEXT('FLUSH TABLES'): FLUSH TABLES 

8.0.4>SELECT STATEMENT_DIGEST_TEXT("SET GLOBAL second_cache.key_buffer_size=128*1024;")\G
STATEMENT_DIGEST_TEXT("SET GLOBAL second_cache.key_buffer_size=128*1024;"): SET GLOBAL `second_cache` . `key_buffer_size` = ? * ? ;

8.0.4>SELECT STATEMENT_DIGEST_TEXT("create TABLE t1 ( a2 int unsigned not null, b2 int unsigned not null, c2 int unsigned not null, primary key (a2), index b2x (b2), index c2x (c2) ) ENGINE=MEMORY;")\G
STATEMENT_DIGEST_TEXT("create TABLE t1 ( a2 int unsigned not null, b2 int unsigned not null, c2 int unsigned not null, primary key (a2), index b2x (b2), index c2x (c2) ) ENGINE=MEMORY;"): CREATE TABLE `t1` ( `a2` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL , `b2` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL , `c2` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY ( `a2` ) , INDEX `b2x` ( `b2` ) , INDEX `c2x` ( `c2` ) ) ENGINE = MEMORY ;
```

If the SQL is not supported, you'll get an error. Like the next one, but there is something special about this response;

```
8.0.4>SELECT STATEMENT_DIGEST_TEXT('HELP SELECT')\G
ERROR 3676 (HY000): Could not parse argument to digest function: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT' at line 1".
```

Did you see what was special? It is the fact that 'HELP' is a valid, but client-side only keyword - i.e. not a server keyword. In any case, an invalid SQL statement will produce a similar situation; an ERROR.

Thus, you can check based on ERROR vs NO ERROR to know whether the passed SQL syntax is valid or not (excluding the very limited set of client-side-only commands, but those would not be of interest to most people).

Summary; `SELECT STATEMENT_DIGEST_TEXT` is a comprehensive SQL parser (while that may not be it's direct/intended function) which can be used in all cases to check the validity of statements quickly and without actually executing them. This is huge progress as far as SQL validity validation is concerned.

Note that you need to have a MySQL server up and running for this. You can pass queries using the `mysql -e` client, or use a pipe to `mysql` etc.

Answer (score 6):

The basic lexer seems to be implemented in sql/sql_lex.cc. You could use/salvage this to build your own test parser.
But this would only check for syntax but not any runtime errors.

edit: For MySQL 8.0+ see [How can I check the SQL syntax in a .sql file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956507/how-can-i-check-the-sql-syntax-in-a-sql-file/49701921#49701921)

Comment: This kind of programmatic solution would be very useful to, for example, validate that a mysqldump result is at least syntactically complete.

Comment: Yes, but doing so would be complex to do. An easier approach (with the same outcome); https://stackoverflow.com/a/49701921/1208218

Answer (score 4):

**TLDR:**

```
>awk '{print "EXPLAIN " $0}' statements.sql | mysql --force -u user -p database | grep "ERROR"
```

---

Strangely, mysql does not have a built-in switch for this, but you can check syntax by adding the `EXPLAIN` statement in front of your queries.

If you have a `statements.sql` file with each statement on one line, prepend `EXPLAIN` in front of all lines with:

```
>awk '{print "EXPLAIN " $0}' statements.sql > check.sql
```

You can then run the statements with the `mysql` command-line tool and use `--force` to have it continue on error. It will print an error for any statements with incorrect syntax.

```
>mysql --force -u user -p database < check.sql
```

Or to only view the lines with errors:

```
>mysql --force -u user -p database < check.sql | grep "ERROR"
```

You can do all of this on one line without creating an intermediate file:

```
>awk '{print "EXPLAIN " $0}' statements.sql | mysql --force -u user -p database | grep "ERROR"
```

Comment: I would add this to make it so the file doesn't need to be a single line. `awk '{if (sub(/;$/,";\n")) printf "EXPLAIN %s", $0; else print $0}' statements.sql` Combine lines ending in semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few free/try-ware products out there that will allow you to connect to a MySQL database or just paste in the script to validate it.  Google is your friend here.
[Mimer will check ANSI-Standard syntax validation](http://developer.mimer.se/validator/index.htm) but probably not handle any MySQL specifics.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possiblities.  If you are using InnoDB tables that support transactions, you can simply execute a `start transaction;` at the beginning of your .sql file and a `rollback;` at the end.  MySQL will output any syntax errors.

If you are testiing `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statements, you could add `LIMIT 0` to the end to prevent these queries from making any database changes, and still have MySQL check the syntax.

Comment: The script may contain statements that cause an implicit commit anyway.

Comment: True, this makes some assumptions about the content of the .sql file.

Answer (score -3):

just run it....

begin transaction

*run it*

rollback

Comment: runing it will give the answer , but is there anything which shows 
me syntax errors in that file ....

Comment: Can't roll back if tables are MyISAM, or if script runs implicit-commit statements (e.g. DDL), or if script contains COMMIT statements.

Comment: @Bill Karwin, their question is quite brief and doesn't mention any of that ;-)

Comment: Prefixing the statement with 'EXPLAIN ' will cause the statement to be parsed and **parser** errors to be reported without changing the data or hogging too much resource on the database.

Comment: DO NOT RUN THIS ON PRODUCTION!

Some statements implicitly and immediately commit. There's quite a few. 

Ref https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sql-statements-that-cause-an-implicit-commit/ for a list