# Searching a tool for checking (My)SQL-Syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, build, continuous-integration

Currently I'm working on an automated build process which will execute some Database changes, too. This could be statements of any kind (ALTER; SELECT; UPDATE; CREATE; DROP...)
I would like to fail the build early if there are any syntax errors in these SQL-Scripts.

After searching around on the web for hours I finally decided to ask the programming volk for any help.

I really dont want to develop this tool myself. Developing it by myself means maintaining it and even risk the loose of data in some cases. (If i need to execute a statement and am unable to rollback.)

What I'm searching for is a (open source) tool which is still maintained. Perfect would be to find this tool in the repositories of some Linux distributions.

Does anybody know such a tool?

I already found some online SQL Checker, but I dont like to send internal data to external networks.

EDIT:
Maybe I need to give some additional background informations. The build process will be used by a continous integration system. I want to be shure the commited sql files are executable. Therefor I would like to add an ant task like "testScript" to the buildscript which will take a SQL-Script, checks the Syntax and fails on failures.
For example it could happen a developer has finished a statement and copy pastes the Statement into the SQL-Script but just selected "TER TABLE" instead of "ALTER TABLE". The Syntax checker I'm searching should find these simple kinds of errors, which will fail the build on a later stage, and cause the build to fail early. In the Best case it can output the faulty statement and the position to safe some time on correcting the mistakes.

Comment: You can check answer of same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956507/how-can-i-check-the-sql-syntax-in-a-sql-file

Comment: I saw these answers but none of that fits to my question. transactions: develope testing tool myself | online checker: data out of private network | use basic lexer: develope tool myself

Comment: If your sql statements are each on their own line, you can validate sql syntax by running a simple sequence of commands. I added an answer explaining how here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37019893/28037

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/), it has a [code complition feature](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/sql-coding.html) with Automatic SQL syntax check function.

Open new SQL document, write some code, or open existent SQL file, and you will see syntax errors if they are.

Comment: Is it possible to use this check as part of a build process? for  example call ´dbforge -checksql test.sql´ ?

Comment: Currently, syntax check does not support command line. You can suggest this feature on Features User Voice page - http://devart.uservoice.com/forums/77293-dbforge-studio-for-mysql